# What is meaning of `T&` when returing `T` from function?

Tags: c++, reference

I see some code like this:

```
const std::vector<obj>& value = function();
```

And `function()` define as follow:

```
std::vector<obj> function()
{
   std::vector<obj> v {/* ... */};
   return v; 
}
```

What is meaning of `&` in `const std::vector<obj>& value` ? is get a reference or copy of local `function()` variable ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is declaring `value` to be a reference to constant `std::vector<obj>`.

References that can bind to temporaries (references-to-const and rvalue-references) can extend the lifetime of the object they reference under some circumstances though, and this is one of those circumstances.  That means that `function`'s return value has its lifetime extended to the lifetime of `value`.

Pre-C++17 this could, in theory, avoid making an extra copy from the return value of `function` to `value` (though every compiler I know of would have elided the copy anyway).  Since C++17 it's guaranteed that no copy is made, so lifetime-extension like this doesn't serve much of a purpose anymore.

Comment: Um, no. `auto && value = function();` - Here we have a non-const reference to the returned object, with lifetime extension kicking in just the same. It's not the const that's special. That is just an historic curiosity.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes, I mentioned rvalue references in the second paragraph.  Added an extra word to clarify that it's only lvalue-references to non-const that don't perform lifetime extension.

Comment: Of course they won't do it, the program won't compile. Which negates the UB argument you seem to make.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's true.  I axed that entire paragraph.